# vimdiff: Is there a possibility to find out if the cursor is in a DiffAdd block?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I'm trying to find out in a script if the current cursor position is a block of lines that were added. Is this somehow possible using vim script?

So far I tried to match for the background color of the current line and the highlight group but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to point you to a place in the documentation and call it a day but that kind of task, specifically, is not super easy to figure out.

So… internally, highlight groups have numerical IDs associated to them, which makes the whole mechanism kind of opaque, but you can find variants of the following command floating around the internet, that make it somewhat easier to identify the highlight groups affecting the text under your cursor:

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

See `:help synid()` and `:help synIDattr()`.

The problem with this, is that Vim makes a difference between two kinds of highlight groups: those that concern the *syntax* of your text and those that concern the *UI* of the editor. This is a problem because `synID()` only works on *syntax* highlight groups and `DiffAdd` is a *UI* highlight group.

But you are certainly not the first user who needs that because there is a built-in function, `:help diff_hlID()`, for that exact purpose:

```
:echo synIDattr(diff_hlID(line("."), col(".")), "name")
DiffAdd
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a very insightful answer, as you always do. I know you are familiar with the XY problem. The way I read the question was: X = figure out if the cursor is in a DiffAdd block, Y = get the highlight group. Out of sheer curiosity, would you know a way to solve X in a more direct fashion?

Comment: Well, the XY problem is a bit of a plague here on SO, but it doesn't appear to be the case with this question. The way OP tried to solve his problem was kind of wrong (with background colors) be he was generally on the right track because Vim doesn't expose any direct way to answer his question. AFAIK, starting with `diff_hlID()` is the only working method and it is not exactly intuitive, even after reading the related documentation. Note that checking the current highlight group is *relatively* common, for checking if the cursor is in a comment block or something like that.

Comment: "checking the current highlight group is relatively common" - I wasn't aware of that. Thank you once more.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer as this does exactly the job and I could not find it! One additional question: Would it in a similar way also be possible to detect a `DiffDelete` block as my cursor cannot move into them but jumps over them?

Comment: No cursor means no information for the highlight group at the cursor, I'm afraid.

Comment: All right I already thought it would be this way. Thank you nevertheless!